# If I'm playing the V in G can I use the D major scale to transition back with a fill

Tags: scales, chord-progressions

If I play a melody on the V that leads back to G is it incorrect to play the major scale from D since it contains a c#?

Comment: Welcome! The answer is kind of layered here. One is "Well, you can play whatever the heck you want," and some general wisdom about every "wrong note" being able to ornamentify into a right note. But I would tend to think in chords rather than scales, and while you *could* use a major 7th chord as a V, it would be much more common to either be dominant 7th (C natural) or no 7th (just avoid C). Once you start talking melodically, it has a lot to do with the notes around it and what's a neighbor of what (passing tone from C nat to D? sure!).

Comment: (Broader philosophical note: If you're improvising, there ain't no such thing as "incorrect." Stand behind whatever you played—spin it, sell it, bend it, resolve it, but don't second-guess it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to play over `G: V I`

If you really want to think in terms of chord/scale system, instead of *playing in the key of...*, then the `V` would be `D` mixolydian as the basic scale, then for the `I` you would play `G` ionian.

IMO it's simpler to just think of that as either playing in `G` major - because `D` mixolydian is just one of the rotations of the `G` major scale - or play it as broken chords with embellishments.

If you had the chords in the reverse order, as `G: I V`, you could introduce the `C#` as a way to *tonicize* the `D`. That would be using the `C#` while playing over the `G` chord, or using the `C#` in `G` major rather than `C` natural.

Some might call that `G` lydian, but you don't necessarily need to be that literal about scale and mode naming.

Playing a `C#` in `G` major is *not unusual*. It can be considered either the lower chromatic neighbor or temporary leading tone of `D`, the fifth degree of the scale. The point is that in a progression like `G: ii V I` you can regard that as all being in `G` major, while still using a `C#`, without the need to refer to `D` major, `G` lydian, etc.

When you talk about "playing scales over chords" it might be better to call it "embellishing" or "decorating" the harmony. Those embellishments can involve all kinds of chromatic, non-diatonic tones that *do not undermine the harmony or tonality*. Chromatically embellished `G` major is still `G` major.

Answer (score 0):

The Bebop scale uses both, so why not? But it depends **where** that pesky C♯ as opposed to the better fitting C♮ gets played.

On the other hand, C♯/D♭ is the Blue note in key G. So, in some circumstances, Blues and jazz in particular, it will fit rather well.

So - both, or either, will do a job in its own right.